# Анимация картинки для сайта

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Добра! 
Как сделать следующую анимацию? Есть один блок, и к нему должны присоединится по очереди еще несколько. Но самое главное, чтобы анимация началась, только когда пользователь прокрутит сайт до нужного места.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/matthieua/WOW